# Subprocess management - Killing a subprocess

Tags: python, macos, audio

I have been trying to make a python script that will play on Mac OS X and I have gotten it to work with a .py script in Terminal, but I can't stop it. 
I have been trying for weeks, `os.kill()`, `process.terminate()`, everything I could find on other StackOverflow questions. Here is my code, can anyone tell me the proper way to terminate this sub-process? (I believe I am using python 2.7)

```
import time
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["afplay", "/Users/0095226/Desktop/introsong.wav"])
time.sleep(4)
(WHATEVER KILLS IT HERE PLEASE)
```

Comment: if you found my answer useful, could you accept it by pressing the green tick next to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) as you can assign the process handle to a variable and later kill it.

```
import time
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["calc"])
time.sleep(4)
p.kill()
```

The other method is to use `os.kill()` along with `signal.SIGINT` to kill the process, as seen here:

```
import time
import signal
import subprocess
import os

p = subprocess.Popen(["calc"])
time.sleep(4)
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

We are able to access the PID (Process ID) and therefore we can kill it using `os.kill()`. `signal` is the module which contains codes for how to kill the process, e.g. send it the abort (SIGABRT), interrupt (SIGINT) etc.

Comment: Thank you! The first solution you gave me worked thank you, sorry for not responding promptly I could not test this until now.